# When running with errexit (-e) how can I expect a nonzero return code and fail otherwise?

Tags: bash

When the errexit option is enabled any failing command will cause the script to exit.  I want to invert this behavior for certain commands that are expected to fail.  That is: I want to continue **only if** the indicated command fails.

I currently do something like this, it's ugly:

```
some_test() { 
    # retuns nonzero if some condition is met, and zero otherwise
}

some_change() {
    # makes a change that should alter the return code of the above test
}

set -e

some_test
echo "expected success, found it"

some_change

set +e
some_test           # expect failure

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
   echo "expected failure, found success"
   exit(1)
else
   echo "expected failure, found it"
fi

set -e

# ...more testing below
```

I am looking for something more concise.  I know that I can *tolerate* a failing command like this:

```
some_test
some_change
some_test && true
```

But I don't want to merely tolerate failure, I want to assert failure.  If the second test passes, I want my script to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if my_command; then false; else true; fi
```

I don't believe it's possible to emulate this using conditional gymnastics.